# Use function of DLL in VBScript

Tags: dll, vbscript

I want to use a function of my Encryption.dll in my VBScript.

If I try to register the dll with `regsvr32 /i Encryption.dll` I get the error that the dll is loaded, but he can't register the file because there is no DllRegistryServer-Entrypoint.

So I tried another way as I read in a forum:

```
Set yourClass = CreateObject("Encryption.Hashing")
```

There I'm getting a ActiveX error.

Anymore ideas of what I can do?

Comment: Is it a native or .NET DLL? Which language is it written in?

Comment: It is written in C++
But i don't know if it is a native or a .NET. This is the first Time that i work with DLL and i have only the job to integrate the DLL. I did not write this file.

Comment: If you try to add a reference to that DLL in Visual Studio you make get a better sense of what it contains and where the entrypoint is.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe the DLL was compiled improperly?  Do you have the source?  If not, try something like Telerik's JustDecompile and see if it can decompile it.  This is not the end all be all kind of test but if it's a .NET dll, you should be able to decompile it.  If it's a native DLL, there should be an error.

Without knowing that, there's several reasons you could be having problems.
Try creating a wrapper that exports the functions you need; test it in VS and then build it and try installing it again. Oh, one more thing.  Native Libs have a .lib file that usually comes with the DLL if it's meant to be linked to for invoking purposes.  That .lib and it's corresponding header files will be what you need to write a wrapper.  Cheers.